# G+ author image for blog posts not showing in search results, but does in rich snippet tool

Tags: search-results, rich-snippets, google-authorship

I have registered my Google authorship e-mail, and my blog posts are on the same domain. Why is my G+ profile image not appearing in SERPs? I have e-mail registered and verified for Google authorship.

All my posts have the same problem, and no profile image of mine appears. Though, when testing it in the [rich snippet tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets), the profile image DOES appear:Why could this be?

Comment: Note that as of 8/28/2014, [Authorship markup is no longer supported in web search](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6083347?rd=1). See [this](http://searchengineland.com/goodbye-google-authorship-201975) for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google only shows your image if it considers you a relevant author on the subject matter (subject matter expert may be debatable as most indications are that they just check how relevant you are as an author but it will probably move there if not already checked).

When the program first rolled out it was easy to get your picture in the SERPs, but they've increased the requirements to have your picture shown and reduced the number of authors showing per page.

Google Authorship Purge: http://www.virante.org/blog/2013/12/19/authorshippocalypse-google-authorship-penguin-finally-appeared/

Answer (score 1):

After some update **Google remains to show only the popular blog** with high PageRank and domain authority. So you need to improve your website in order to get resulted.